# Listing root files along with directory indication

Tags: android, shell, su

I am trying to get all the files in Android root directory. I want to know which are files,directory or symlinks. I tried with ls -Fl command but it returned with same result as ls -l. If I use adb or Terminal Emulator app the same command gives me the list as well as indication for directory as d,symlinks as ld .How do I achieve it through code?

ls -F though gives me indication but without the full listing though. What I have observed is 2 letter commands after - is not working like ls -Fl. Any solutions?

```
                boolean suAvailable = Shell.SU.available();
                if (suAvailable) {

                    try {
                        String line;
                        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                        OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
                        InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
                        InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();

                        stdin.write(("ls -Fl\n").getBytes());
                        stdin.write("exit\n".getBytes());
                        stdin.flush();

                        stdin.close();
                        BufferedReader br =
                                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            Log.d("[Output]", line);
                        }
                        br.close();
                        br =
                                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stderr));
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            Log.e("[Error]", line);
                        }
                        br.close();

                        process.waitFor();
                        process.destroy();

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
```

Comment: Use the `File` class.

Comment: I use the File class only mostly. But for directory which doesnt have read access i.e. in root directories,I use this shell approach.